# Efficient method for converting text to phone keypad

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have the following code for converting a string containing alphanumeric characters to a string of numbers that can be entered into a phone using the phone's keypad:

```
string text = "sometext containing spaces and numbers 12345";
Dictionary<char, char> alphabetMapping = new Dictionary<char, char>();
alphabetMapping['a'] = '2';
alphabetMapping['b'] = '2';
alphabetMapping['c'] = '2';
alphabetMapping['d'] = '3';
alphabetMapping['e'] = '3';
alphabetMapping['f'] = '3';
alphabetMapping['g'] = '4';
alphabetMapping['h'] = '4';
alphabetMapping['i'] = '4';
alphabetMapping['j'] = '5';
alphabetMapping['k'] = '5';
alphabetMapping['l'] = '5';
alphabetMapping['m'] = '6';
alphabetMapping['n'] = '6';
alphabetMapping['o'] = '6';
alphabetMapping['p'] = '7';
alphabetMapping['q'] = '7';
alphabetMapping['r'] = '7';
alphabetMapping['s'] = '7';
alphabetMapping['t'] = '8';
alphabetMapping['u'] = '8';
alphabetMapping['v'] = '8';
alphabetMapping['w'] = '9';
alphabetMapping['x'] = '9';
alphabetMapping['y'] = '9';
alphabetMapping['z'] = '9';
alphabetMapping['1'] = '1';
alphabetMapping['2'] = '2';
alphabetMapping['3'] = '3';
alphabetMapping['4'] = '4';
alphabetMapping['5'] = '5';
alphabetMapping['6'] = '6';
alphabetMapping['7'] = '7';
alphabetMapping['8'] = '8';
alphabetMapping['9'] = '9';
alphabetMapping['0'] = '0';
alphabetMapping['.'] = '0';
alphabetMapping[','] = '0';
alphabetMapping['@'] = '0';
alphabetMapping['*'] = '*';
alphabetMapping['#'] = '#';
alphabetMapping[' '] = '0'; // not sure if this underscore or space

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in text)
{
    sb.Append(alphabetMapping[c]);
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

The output:
`76638398026682464640772237026306862377012345`

Not that this has much practical use, but some automated phone systems ask for passwords that may contain letters so I wrote this code for helping with that.

Is there a more efficient method for this or am I on the right track?

Comment: I've got a paper airplane.  But neither of us have a question.

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking if this is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: I accidentally posted without finishing asking the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: This seems appropriate to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fewer lines of code if you grouped all of your items together.

```
var allValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string,char>>()

allValues.Add(new KeyValuePair("abc2","2"));
allValues.Add(new KeyValuePair("def3","3"));
etc, etc

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in text)
{
    var matched = allValues.FirstOrDefault(kvp=> kvp.Key.Contains(c));
    if(matched != null)
    {
       sb.Append(matched.Value);
    }
    else
    {
       sb.Append(" ");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

It's probably not computationally more efficient, but it's less for a human to read.

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way to convert phone letters to their respective numbers is to use Regular Expressions. Here is the function that I use. It may need to be tweaked to fit your scenario.

```
internal static string ConvertPhoneTexttoNumber(string PhoneNumber)
{
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[abcABC]", "2");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[defDEF]", "3");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[ghiGHI]", "4");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[jklJKL]", "5");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[mnoMNO]", "6");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[pgrsPGRS]", "7");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[tuvTUV]", "8");
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[wxyzWXYZ]", "9");

    //remove all non alphanumeric characters
    PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[\W]", "");             

    return PhoneNumber;
 }
```

This solution will work for any number of characters in a string. If you want to keep the parentheses and dashes remove this line:

```
PhoneNumber = Regex.Replace(PhoneNumber, @"[\W]", "");
```

**Note:** If you don't know how to use Regular Expressions, here is a great tutorial:
https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs

Answer (score 1):

Considering the size of the dataset (alphanumeric characters and letters) and the intended application, this seems like the most logical and seemingly optimal way to do it. If you wanted to improve the performance you could use a HashSet, but I'm not sure you would see any measurable gain from that with this dataset.